# Get the last parameter with built in bash command

Tags: bash, command, arguments

In Bash there are several built in command like `!!, !:1, !:*` to access respectively last command executed, first argument, or all arguments.

How can I access to the last argument **without** have to count the number of argument, like typying

`ls !:2`?

I was expected:

```
$ one two three
$ ls !:-1
$ ls three
```

But it return `$ ls one two`

Comment: Try this: `ls !$`

Comment: Technically, they are not commands; they are expansions.